# How to display the else condition "Number entered more than 10” five times?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I really need some help, the question is a program asks the user to enter a name and number of choices. If the number of choices is less than 10, then display their name as much as that number. If not, display the message “Number entered more than 10” five times.
How to display the else condition "Number entered more than 10” five times?

```
name = input('What is your name: ')
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))

for i in range(number):
    if (number > 0) and (number <= 10):
        print(name)
    else:
        print("Number entered more than 10")
```

Comment: You'll need a loop (as you are learning, I suggest you search, give us here your feedback and questions if any)

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean to allow the user 5 times to type the input? Or literally just print it 5 times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Just use separate for loops in different conditions:

```
 name = input('What is your name: ')
 number = int(input('Enter a number: '))

 if number > 0 and number <= 10:
     for i in range(number):
        print(name)
 else:
     for i in range(5):
        print("Number entered more than 10")
```

Comment: Best to avoid parenthesis in conditions, if its not complex and grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
  print("Message")
```

This one prints "Message" 10 times. I leave the rest as an exercise :)

Comment: Consider adding suggestions as comments, rather than answers

Answer (score 0):

I have just added what is needed to your attempt. See below

```
# read your inputs
name = input('What is your name: ')
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))

if 0<number<=10:
    # if in range, print it that many times
    print("\n".join([name]*number))
else:
    # if not print 5 times
    print("\n".join(["Number entered more than 10"]*5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    else:
        print("Number entered more than 10" * 5)
```

or, if you'd like to have prints in separate lines:

```
    else:
        print("Number entered more than 10\n" * 5)
```

the `\n` stands for new line to be added after every line.